# drupal 7- on updating field's integer value and keep a running tally

Tags: drupal-7

I have a site where I want to let a user edit a field (of the integer type, something like an odometer reading) and when the user puts in a value, Drupal will calculate the difference between the latest value and the one that was put there before and keep a running tally. If the tally exceeds a certain amount, another field will be populated with a status (or a number), such as "needs servicing." I think I can use the Rules module for some of this. I don't know how to use the value that comes before the newer value, though. How would I do that, or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Possible but you may want to provide more specific details of "display a flag elsewhere" and ask a more constructive question other than "is this possible"

Comment: I want to let user enter an odometer reading, then at a later time, come back and update that odometer reading. and if the difference between the two values exceeds a certain amount, then populate a field with a status (or a number), such as "needs servicing." So my main functionality is to track a field that takes an integer value and then signal the user that service needs to happen.

Comment: Is the "needs servicing" field in the same content type? [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) may be a possible module or, as I mentioned in your previous question, check out the [Computed Field module](http://drupal.org/project/computed_field). Also, you can edit your question to add the details you put in your comment above.

Comment: yes, it could be. I have a view made of the fields in that content type for the admins to see as an overview. I want to be able to flag nodes as needing servicing, and actually there are several levels of servicing. Thanks.

Comment: As for computed field, I don't have the php skills that are needed to use it. It's possible I could find someone else, though.